# mkvirtualenv returns -bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-yosemite, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper successfully with pip. I'm running OSX Yosemite. I tested it when I first installed it (following [instructions at newcoder.io](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/))and it worked, but now it doesn't. I tried using the "source" command: source "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.sh" but I get the response "-bash: cd: python: No such file or directory."

Did I tweak something that knocked it offline? Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I got it, I think! I had been using "source" plus the path that the install program told me the program was in (see above) instead of the one that is recommended in similar questions. (OK, so I was overthinking this one). Anyway. I'm happy, I got it on my own!

Comment: Add some code or anything that we can look at please.